# Mapped network drive resets on restart

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, powershell

I have a problem where my mapped network drive becomes unavailable after a restart, trying various solutions to make it persistent [`/persistent:yes` when re-mapping via PowerShell, etc.]:

- `net use Z: "\\10.0.1.145\xyz"` connects the drive fine but doesn't persist past a restart

I wrote a script to automate this for me:

- ```
  If ( !(Test-Path -Path "\\10.0.1.145\") ) {
     net use Z: "\\10.0.1.145\xyz" /persistent:yes
  }
  ```

  - The odd thing is: 
    `Test-Path -Path "\\\10.0.1.145\\"` = `false` 
    `Test-Path -Path "\\\10.0.1.145\xyz"` = `true`
- `net use Z: "\\10.0.1.145\xyz" /persistent:yes` gets the same result as the two `Test-Path` commands, with the only difference being `Z:` is accessible via CMD *(`Z:` has been accessible via Explorer all along)*

How can I map `Z:` persistently to `10.0.1.145` or reliably automate this if the former doesn't work?

Comment: is there a reason to NOT use `New-PSDrive`? in my experience, using that with `-Persist` and `-Scope  Global` results in a drive map that stays thru reboots.

Comment: The reason was only my unawareness. Just read over the docs and it sounds like it could solve the problem. Based on the command I used above, would you be able to tell me what the New-PSDrive command would be to map the drive?

Comment: i think something like this would work >>> `New-PSDrive -Name 'k' -PSProvider FileSystem -Root '\\MySysName\D$\Temp' -Scope 'Global' -Persist` <<< ///// for more detail, take a look at `Get-Help New-PSDrive -Examples`.

Answer (score 0):

When Windows 10 logs on, there is a timing issue which causes it to attempt
to map the network drives before the network is available, so all
network mappings are disabled.

To fix:

- Run *Start > Edit Group Policy* (or `gpedit.msc`)
- Navigate to
  *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Logon*
- Set "Always Wait for the Network at Computer Startup and Logon" to "Enabled"
- Click on Apply/OK.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I followed the instructions and the drive seems to persist. However, when I open VS Code the program still doesn't have access to the drive. Any idea why programs wouldn't be able to see the drive?

Comment: Does Explorer see and display its contents?

Comment: Yes, it shows folders and I can traverse them correctly

Comment: If you delete and recreate the share mapping, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to workaround by adding the credentials to Generic Credentials in Credential Manager:

`cmdkey /generic:10.0.1.145 /user:yourUser /pass:yourPass`

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem for me<sup>1</sup>..

1. Create `C:\Scripts\NetworkDriveMap.ps1` script (create `Scripts` folder if not exist),
2. Create `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\NetworkDriveMap.cmd` script,
3. Done.

`.cmd` script will be executed at Windows Startup, it will set the permissions and call `.ps1` script, which will try to reconnect with the shared network (check `%Temp%\StartupLogs.txt` file after the reboot).

Here are the scripts

##### NetworkDriveMap.ps1

```
$i=3

while($True){

    $error.clear()

    $MappedDrives = Get-SmbMapping |where -property Status -Value Unavailable -EQ | select LocalPath,RemotePath

    foreach( $MappedDrive in $MappedDrives)

    {
        try {

            New-SmbMapping -LocalPath $MappedDrive.LocalPath -RemotePath $MappedDrive.RemotePath -Persistent $True

        } catch {

            Write-Host "There was an error mapping $MappedDrive.RemotePath to $MappedDrive.LocalPath"
        }
    }

    $i = $i - 1

    if($error.Count -eq 0 -Or $i -eq 0) {break}

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
}
```

##### NetworkDriveMap.cmd

```
PowerShell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser" >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
PowerShell -File "%SystemDrive%\Scripts\NetworkDriveMap.ps1" >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The source of this work is taken from [this article](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/could-not-reconnect-all-network-drives.html), with minor edits (paths fixes, quotes).